# TypeError while logging in python

Tags: python, string, logging, typeerror

I have an JSON input and I am trying to log the value of a specific key. But It's showing  me TypeError: Not all arguments converted during string formatting.

```
msg = {'job_id' = '11', 'status' = 'complete', 'tr_no' = 'S$Wed'}

logger.info('Process Completed:')
logger.info(msg["tr_no"], 'Successful' )
```

I am using python 2.7. I tried it in following way as well but got same error message

```
logger.info(str(msg["tr_no"]), 'Successful' )
```

Comment: Is `msg` the JSON input? It doesn't look like proper Python syntax (neither does it look like proper JSON syntax). Showing us the full traceback will also help. :-)

Comment: yes, it's JSON input. I will not be able to copy it , so I typed in manually. Thanks !

Comment: `msg = {'job_id': '11', 'status': 'complete', 'tr_no': 'S$Wed'}`? Are you sure this is the actual code that reproduces your TypeError? Please post a [mcve]. We're kinda missing Complete and Verifiable here. 

Answer (score -1):

```
import logging as logger
msg = dict(job_id='11', status='complete', tr_no='S$Wed')
logger.info('Process Completed:')
logger.info(msg["tr_no"], 'Successful' )
```

Try this code ..... .

Or replace 2nd line as :

```
msg = {'job_id':'11', 'status':'complete', 'tr_no':'S$Wed'}
```

Thank you .